# initialization of Hangfire servers for multitenants application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant, hangfire

I am facing issue with add Hangfire servers for multi tenant application. In my application startup I am looping through all tenants and initialize and add set of jobs for each tenant. It is adding servers in each tenant database but the jobs are added only to first tenant database. I don't see any job in other tenants databases and dashboard. Following is the code I am trying:

```
foreach (var tenant in TenantConvention.GetTenants())
            {

                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                 .UseSqlServerStorage(DbServer.GetConnectionString(tenant));

                var sqlStorage = new SqlServerStorage(DbServer.GetConnectionString(tenant));

                app.UseHangfireDashboard($"/dashboard/{tenant}-Jobs", new DashboardOptions
                {
                    Authorization = new[] { new HangfireAuthFilter() }

                }, sqlStorage);

                var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
                {                   
                    ServerName = tenant//string.Format("{0}.{1}", tenant, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                };

                var jobStorage = JobStorage.Current;
                app.UseHangfireServer(options, jobStorage);               

                var schedulars = ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances();
                foreach (var schedular in schedulars) {
                    schedular.Init();
                }

            }
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I think you should use `BackgroundJobServerOptions`

Comment: I am using it. You have example of how to use it in this situation. @Aria

Comment: I am using Hangfire also , but I didn't crossed with this approach but I am looking for this also...Trying to help.

Comment: ok Thank you @Aria

Comment: As you know you configure SQL server storage of `GlobalConfiguration` to first `tanent` connection for this reason all the job will create in first DB.

Comment: but in next iteration the sql server storage changes to next tenant

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported by default so you should use `EnqueuedState` as the following:

```
  Hangfire.States.IState state = new Hangfire.States.EnqueuedState
                {
                    Queue = serverName
                };  
  client.Create(() => Console.WriteLine(serverName), state);
```

so to real test I have created two DB named `DB1` and `DB2` in SQL Server and test the below code (Works nice):

```
string[] connections = new string[] {
                "Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DB1",
                "Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DB2"}; 
foreach (string strConnection in connections)
     {
          string serverName = "str" + DateTime.Now.Ticks;
          var sqlStorage = new Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage(strConnection);
          var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
            {
                ServerName =serverName  
            };
          JobStorage.Current = sqlStorage;
          IBackgroundJobClient client = new BackgroundJobClient();
          Hangfire.States.IState state = new Hangfire.States.EnqueuedState
                {
                    Queue = serverName
                };  
          client.Create(() => Console.WriteLine(serverName), state); 
     }
```

The above code is sample after running I have seen two job created but in different Db as screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: but how it will help in recurring jobs. I have a lot of recurring jobs. Weekly daily etc

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli It is just the same, pass `name` as first parameter to `RecurringJob` like `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(name,method,Cron.Yearly);`

Comment: when i use queue with recurring job Add, it adds multiple job queues to same database. Again all the data goes to first db

Comment: Have you tried without using `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration`, as you can see I haven't use it in my sample code.

Comment: same thing. Everything landing in first server

Comment: Did you mean it always save it in first DB by `it adds multiple job queues to same database` sentence ?, if yes then why it works for me ?

Comment: I think this is because i am not using IBackgroundJobClient client = new BackgroundJobClient(); to add jobs. This has no option to add recurring job

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162281/discussion-between-aria-and-irfan-tahirkheli).